# I am trying to create a dice roller that i can adjust how many dice are rolled and adjust how many numbers it outputs based on that

Tags: python

As mentioned in the title I'm in the proses of creating a dice roller that lets the user decide how many dice they want to roll without limiting the amount of dice so far I've gotten it to a stage where it can roll the dice then print the results of one of the dice but I can't figure out how to get it to display multiple rolls I was thinking of getting the code to create variables for the outputs and print them all but I have no clue if this it possible or not

```
import sys

h = 0
r = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')
while r != 'n':
    if r == 'y':
        m = input('What do you want to be able to role up to\n')
        t = input('How many times do you want to want to roll the dice\n')
        for h in range(int(t)):
            d = random.randint(1, int(m))
            h = h+1
        print(d)
        question = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid response. Please type "y" or "n".')
        question = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')
print('Good-bye!')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just put `print(d)` inside the loop by indenting it...

Comment: thanks that was a complete accident I think I just forgot to change that since this it version 3 of the code and I just coped and pasted it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, move `print(d)` inside the loop and you will have what you want. Moreover `h = h+1` is totally useles, since the iteration of the for loop is automatic.

Comment: What do you mean because without h = h+1 there is nothing to incriminate h. Edit; And the code is putting in the amount of outputs it’s requested to but if the code had an increment other then the h = h+1 then it would only have half the outputs